# Selecting a table in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a table in a word doc that I want to use VBA to select specific cells with. Every document I make follows a template that has a 4xZ table which means I have 4 columns and a varying number of rows depending on the document.

What I want to do is select the 3rd column of the table except the 1st row since that's the header and the iterate down each cell, grab the value and run it through a switch statement so I can change the color of the cell based on the value.

I found this bit of code [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1628-excel-select-column-except-header-first-row.html):

```
Sub SelectColumn()
'Updateby20140510
Dim xColIndex As Integer
Dim xRowIndex As Integer
xIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
xRowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, xIndex).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(2, xIndex), Cells(xRowIndex, xIndex)).Select
End Sub
```

And I supposed I could modify the code to say:

```
xIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Columns(3)
```

But if that works and selects the 3rd column and all the rows in the 3rd column except the 1st, I don't understand how to continue that and start iterating. I know the iteration code would be something like:

```
For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
...
Next
```

But I don't get how to reference the selection of the 3rd column, 2 row down in the for loop. Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** 
I realize the above code is excel. So after hours of digging and to no avail I just decided to do it the quick and dirty method. Here's the code for that:

```
For Each oClm In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns
        If clmNum = 3 Then
            ' Loop through each cell in the current row.
            For Each oCell In oClm.Cells
                If rowNum = 2 Then
                    ' Set sCellText equal to text of the cell.
                    ' Note: This section can be modified to suit
                    ' your programming purposes.
                    oCellText = oCell.Range
                    oCellText = Left(oCellText, Len(oCellText) - 1)
                    oCellText = CStr(oCellText)

                    Select Case oCellText
                        Case "Complete"
                           oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = wdGreen
                        Case "Partial"
                           oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = wdYellow
                        Case "Incomplete"
                           oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = wdRed
                    End Select
                End If
                rowNum = rowNum + 1
            Next oCell
        End If
        clmNum = clmNum + 1
    Next oClm
```

The only problem now is, I break point right before the switch statement and the value inside `oCellText` is "Complete" but it skips over that in the switch statement. I have no idea why, it should go into the statement but it acts like it's not the same. Which is why I have the `cstr` line, I guess it didn't do anything but didn't hurt to try.

Any ideas why the case statement is failing?

**Edit 2:**
I found out why the case is failing. Because `oCellText` has a new line after it. I removed that with this code:

```
oCellText = Replace(oCellText, Chr(13), "")
```

But the case statement still isn't matching. Any ideas?

**Edit 3:**
I got everything to work now. But I'm just unhappy that I have to go through the cells with a nested for loop, was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: That's Excel code you have there, not Word.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah i just realized that, I'm brand new to vba so I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

much easier way if you are still looking
you can address cells directly

```
   for y = 2 to activedocument.tables(1).rows.count

   activedocument.tables(1).cell(3,y).select

    ' do your stuff here

   next y
```